# Trying to submit my laravel form without the page refreshing

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am trying to submit my form without having to refresh the page. I haven't been successful I keep getting error message in the console log that the serever is saying the page is wrong.I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Can someone help me please? I am using laravel,ajax. Here is my code. Thanks in advance

```
   //Ajax

$('.formform' ).submit(
    function( e ) {
        $.ajax( {
            url: '{{ url('profileupdate') }}',
            type: 'POST',
            data: new FormData( this ),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(result){
                console.log(result);
            }
        } );
        e.preventDefault();
    } 
);


             //The form
    {!!Form::open(['url'=>['profileupdate',Auth::user()->id],'method'=>'POST','files'=>true,'class'=>'formform formform2','enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}

                    <div style="position:relative; left:.5em; font-size:1.3em;">
ADD YOUR VIDEO!<br>

                        </div>
                        <br>
                    {{Form::file('video',array('id'=>'file','class'=>'thefile'))}}

                    <label for="file"  class="btn btn-default" style="background:none;">Choose a file</label> <span class="tt"></span>








                    {{Form::text('Company','',array('placeholder'=>'Company Name','class'=>'form-control'))}}

{{Form::text('city','',array('placeholder'=>'City and State','class'=>'form-control', 'size'=>'35px','height'=>'15px','id'=>'location-input','autocomplete'=>'off'))}}

{{Form::text('zip_code','',array('placeholder'=>'Zip Code','class'=>'form-control'))}}

 {{Form::text('Phone_Number','',array('placeholder'=>'Phone Number','class'=>'form-control'))}}



{{Form::submit('Submit', array('class'=>'btn btn-warning form-control','id'=>'submitty profile1_submit','style'=>'border:none; margin-top:3%; margin-bottom:5%;', 'data-toggle'=>"modal",  'data-target'=>"#profile_modal"))}}
{!!Form::close() !!}

   //Here is the route

   Route::post('profileupdate/{id}','Profile1Controller@update');
```

Comment: You’re missing some code. Can you rpint out each part, separately?

Comment: @ThomasEdwards I just edited my code I had forgot to label something. Am I still missing something?

Comment: You’re missing where you open the form. Do give more context as to how these things releate to each other.

Comment: @ThomasEdwards I just now noticed that ...I just fixed it

Comment: I can’t tell from here, but `new FormData( this )` seems to be that `this` is likely the AJAX object, or possibly the function. I’m not sure what’s being sent there. Can you see what data is being sent in the browser when you make that request?

Comment: @ThomasEdwards I am not sure. All I know is that when I go in the console i get an error saying that server responded in 404 error meaning that the page isn't found

Answer (score 2):

You miss the parameter `id` 'profileupdate/{id}'
Change this :

```
url: '{{ url('profileupdate') }}',
```

With

```
 url: {!! route('profileupdate', ['id' => Auth::user()->id  ]) !!}
```

and don't forget to add the token for csrf in data (javascript part)

```
    "_token": $('#token').val()
```

Comment: when I put  {!! route('profileupdate', ['id' => Auth::user()->id  ]) !!}
I get an error message.

Answer (score 1):

Update needs and token if it is post. I also think the way you call the route is wrong.
What I did on my code here is I call a function with the id as parameter and call it using a button:

```
<button type="button" onclick = "submitThisForm({{Auth::user()->id}})"> Submit</button>
```

then the script function contains the ajax post. I use replace to add the id to the route.

```
 function submitThisForm(id){
    url= '{{route('upload-employee-request',[":emp"])}}';
    url= url.replace(':emp', id);

}
```

then finally

```
function submitThisForm(id){
        url= '{{route('upload-employee-request',[":emp"])}}';
        url= url.replace(':emp', id);

        $.ajax( {
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: new FormData( this ),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(result){
                console.log(result);
            }
        } );
        e.preventDefault();


    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try and will update you.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work thanks to Abderrahim Soubai Elidrissi and Dearwolves(Thanks guys)

This is what worked for me

```
 $.ajaxSetup({

        headers: {

            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')

        }

    });


$('.formform' ).submit(
    function( e ) {
        $.ajax( {
            url: '{!! url('profileupdate', ['id' => Auth::user()->id  ]) !!}',
            type: 'POST',
            data: new FormData( this ),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(result){
                alert('form submitted');
            }
        } );
        e.preventDefault();
    } 
);
```