# How to submit my form without reloading with ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, database, laravel

I would like to submit my form without reloading the page after pressing the submit button.But everything I have tried doesn't worked.Can you give me some help with `ajax` code please?

**My view**:

```
<!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header" style="border-bottom: none;padding: 0px 0px;right: 15px;top: 10px;position:relative">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <section>
    <div class="wizard col-md-6" >
    <div class="wizard-inner">
    <div class="connecting-line"></div>
<ul style="border:none !important" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" style="margin: 0px auto">

    <li role="presentation" class="active">
    <a href="#step1" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step1" role="tab" title="Step 1">
<span class="round-tab">
                                    <i class="icon-pencil"></i>
</span>
                    </a>
                    </li>

                    <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                    <a href="#step2" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step2" role="tab" title="Step 2">
                            <span class="round-tab">
                                    <i class="icon-note"></i>
                            </span>
                    </a>
                    </li>
                    <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                    <a href="#step3" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step3" role="tab" title="Step 3">
                            <span class="round-tab">
                                    <i class="icon-check"></i>
                            </span>
                    </a>
                    </li>


                    </ul>
                    </div>

                    <form role="form" action="/career_report" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                    @if(Sentinel::check())
                    <input type="hidden" name="user_id"  value="{{ Sentinel::check()->id }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="username"  value="{{ Sentinel::check()->username }}">
                    @endif

                    <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="{{url()->current()}}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="user_id_posted" value="{{ $event->user->id }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="username_posted" value="{{ $event->user->username }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="career_solution_id" value="{{ $event->id}} ">

                    <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel" id="step1">
                    <h3 style="text-align: center">Why are you reporting this content :</h3>

                    <ul style="list-style: none">
                    <li>

                    <input type="radio" id="box-9" name="why_reporting" value="Spam">
                    <label for="box-9">Spam</label>

                    <div class="check"></div>
                    <small id="box-9-s" style="display: none">I consider this content irrelevant and annoying.</small>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                    <input type="radio" id="box-10" name="why_reporting" value="Fake Profile">
                    <label for="box-10">Fake Profile</label>

                    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
                    <small id="box-10-s" style="display: none">This content was posted by way of a profile that clearly doesn't represent a real person.
                    </small>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                    <input type="radio" id="box-11" name="why_reporting" value="Advertising">
                    <label for="box-11">Advertising</label>

                    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
                    <small id="box-11-s" style="display: none">This content is or contains advertising.
                    </small>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <input type="radio" id="box-12" name="why_reporting" value="Untrustworthy source">
                    <label for="box-12">Untrustworthy source</label>

                    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
                    <small id="box-12-s" style="display: none">This content is from an untrustworthy source and contains unverifiable statements.
                    </small>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <input type="radio" id="box-13" name="why_reporting" value="Defamatory">
                    <label for="box-13">Defamatory</label>

                    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
                    <small id="box-13-s" style="display: none">The reported content is insulting or defamatory to me or other people.
                    </small>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <input type="radio" id="box-14" name="why_reporting" value="Violence or pornography">
                    <label for="box-14">Violence or pornography</label>

                    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
                    <small id="box-14-s" style="display: none">This content contains violence or pornography.
                    </small>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <input type="radio" id="box-15" name="why_reporting" value="Violates IP rights">
                    <label for="box-15">Violates IP rights</label>

                    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
                    <small id="box-15-s" style="display: none">This content includes third-party content (e.g. an image) posted under their own name.
                    </small>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <input type="radio" id="box-16" name="why_reporting" value="Promotes structural distribution measures">
                    <label for="box-16">Promotes structural distribution measures</label>

                    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
                    <small id="box-16-s" style="display: none">This content promotes a chain distribution system, multilevel selling or pyramid sales.
                    </small>
                    </li>
                    <li >
                    <input type="radio" id="box-17" name="why_reporting" value="Other">
                    <label for="box-17" id="other">Other</label>

                    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
                    <div class="form-group" id="mydiv" style="display: none">
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" placeholder="Please let us know why you're reporting this content:
                    " style="resize: none" name="why_reporting_message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    </li>
                    </ul>


                    <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
                        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></li>
                            <li><button style="background-color: #18ba9b;border-color: white" type="button" class="btn btn-primary next-step">Save and continue</button></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="step2">
                    <h3>Why would you like to report this?</h3>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="5" style="resize: none" placeholder="
                    Please let us know why you're reporting this content:" name="additional_message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
                        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></li>
                            <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default prev-step">Previous</button></li>
                            <li><button style="background-color: #18ba9b;border-color: white" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-info-full next-step" id="save">Submit your report</button></li>
                    </ul>

                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="step3">
                    <h2 class="title-box-v2" style="font-size: 17px !important;line-height: 35px">We'll look into this as soon as possible. Thanks for helping us improve the quality of content on Workstickers.</h2>
                    <p style="text-align: center">You have successfully completed all steps.Flagged content and users are reviewed by Workstickers staff 24 hours a day, seven days a week to determine whether they violate Community Guidelines. Accounts are penalized for Community Guidelines violations, and serious or repeated violations can lead to account termination.
                    </p>
                    <div style="text-align: center;margin-top: 50px">If you've changed your mind -  <a href="/delete/ " style="text-decoration: underline;color: #18ba9b;font-weight: 700">Cancel report</a></div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>



<!-- END MY MODAL -->


 <script>
        $(document).on("click",".save",function(){
    e.preventDefault(); //Prevent page from submiting
    $(document).on("click", ".save", function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: 'career_report',
        data: $(".why_reporting").serialize(),
        success: function(store) {

        },
        error: function() {
        }
    });
});
}); 
        </script>
```

**My route**

```
Route::post('career_report', 'CareerSolutionController@careerReport');
```

**My controller**

```
    public function careerReport(requ $request)
    {

        $report = \App\Reports::create([
                        'user_id' => $request['user_id'],
                        'username' => $request['username'],
                        'user_id_posted' => $request['user_id_posted'],
                        'username_posted' => $request['username_posted'],
                        'career_solution_id' =>$request['career_solution_id'],
                        'subject' =>$request['subject'],
                        'why_reporting' =>$request['why_reporting'],
                        'why_reporting_message' =>$request['why_reporting_message'],
                        'additional_message' =>$request['additional_message'],

                    ]);



        if($report != ""){
            flash('Career solution report submited', 'success');
        }else{
            flash('Career solution report', 'warning');
        }

        return Redirect::back();


    }
```

What I have **tried**:

I tried to adapt this to my code, but without success. [Trying to submit my laravel form without the page refreshing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53342189/trying-to-submit-my-laravel-form-without-the-page-refreshing)

Comment: I see that you haven't tried using ajax in your blade file . Then what have you tried?

Comment: @farooq please check now.

Comment: You have to write some javascript and need to link in your blade file. For more info check this [link](https://www.tutsmake.com/laravel-5-7-create-first-ajax-crud-application/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [Jquery Ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp) .

```
    $('#yourFormId').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        method:'POST',
        url:'your process file URL',
        data:data,
        success: function (result) {
            // do something with result
          }
    });
});
```

in this example i have used  [$.Ajax method](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp)

when you use **e.preventDefault();** your form will not be submitted . so you can manually submit it in Javascript . in the submit event , you use Ajax and it sends your form data to your process file and then returns the result . without refreshing page or redirecting .

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working!! I only changed the url with `/career_report`.